# Intellij - Same jar to multiple locations

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Just moving from netbeans to intellij & wanted to get a view on the best way to handle a common task I use in NB.

Each time I build my project I need a jar to go to the normal output directory, but in addition I want a copy to also go into a couple of additional paths to update running machines & speed up my dev flow.

In NB I add this as a task in build.xml - simple .
In Intellij it seems I have two options;

1. create an ant script for my project and then modify that to do the same as NB
2. add artifacts to my project for each path

I need to do this for all of my projects & I need it to be simple so that each project doesn't need a whole load of setup before I can get working on it.  NB was nice - cut and paste 4 lines into build.xml and job done.

For those experienced with Intellij - what's your approach?  Are there some con's of either I'm missing, or perhaps a 3rd way??

Comment: The best way is to rely on IDE independent build systems. Gradle and Bazel are the most flexible ones at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

Just to close this one off.  I've gone for the ant solution.
1. Generate an ant build script for the project
2. Add the copy statements to the artifact.PROJECTNAME:jar ant target

This way it's the same copy statements for each project, just with a jar name update.
Seems easier than adding artifacts for each location I need the file in.